# É possível saber quantos clientes estão conectados ao ServerSocket?

Tags: java, socket

Como eu faço para ver quantos clientes estão conectados no meu `ServerSocket` em java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se é que existe algum *ID* por usuário que ajuda a identificar quem são os clientes, mas em questão de servidores TCP, o que sempre pode ser contado é a conexão feita por um cliente e a partir desta conexão feita podemos obter dados e tentar criar uma identidade para poder distinguir.

### Contando conexões

Dentro do loop `while` usamos o `ServerSocket.accept();` para determinar quando houve a conexão, então a conta seria algo como:

```java
int i = 0;
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8088);
while (true) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    i += 1;
    ...
}
```

Como o loop é "infinito", você pode usar um Thread para mostrar o `i` usando o `System.out` por exemplo. Se você procura contar conexões feitas no exato momento isto deve lhe ajudar.

### Contando endereços remotos

Porém isto apenas conta as conexões feitas. Geralmente o cliente conecta, recebe os dados e desconecta. Se for uma página de web, então a cada imagem, js, css, dentro da página poderá gerar uma nova conexão, ou seja um cliente gera várias conexões.

> Note: Os navegadores de web geralmente usam a instrução `Connection: keep-alive` nos "headers" de requisição, o que deve fazer o que indica que o navegador deve manter a conexão aberta para os elementos na página, porém esta conexão nem sempre vai ficar aberta.

Conseguimos contar o número de conexões feitas, agora o que precisamos é dar uma *identidade* para cada cliente.

Um exemplo de identificar o cliente é usar `socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();` (que pode não ser 100% garantido, mas isto é outra história) combinado a uma lista. O código deve ficar algo assim:

```java
List<String> clientes = new ArrayList<String>();
...
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8088);
while (true) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    String addr = ss.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
    if (!clientes.contains(addr)) {
        clientes.add(addr);
    }
}
```

Desta maneira iremos salvar todos endereços conectados (lembre-se nestes casos é sempre necessário usar um Thread, ou o seu socket estar em um Thread separado) e para contar bastaria usar `clientes.size()`.

### Contador em tempo real

O exemplo que passei conta as conexões, mas não limpa a lista, de forma que o número nunca vai diminuir, ele só vai aumentar. Neste caso, se o que você necessita é um contador em "tempo real", você pode usar um `HashMap` para criar um lista em que os itens *expiram* (semelhante ao que os contadores online fazem).

Crie uma `HashMap` assim:

```java
Map<String, Date> clientes = new HashMap<String, Date>();
```

- `String` vai ter o "endereço".
- `Date` será usado para verificar se os dados devem expirar.

O "Servidor" deve ficar assim:

```java
Map<String, Date> clientes = new HashMap<String, Date>();

ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8088);
while (true) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    String addr = ss.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();

    // Atualiza o horário de um endereço existente ou adiciona um novo endereço.
    clientes.put(addr, new Date());
}
```

E em outro método (o qual deve ter acesso a variável `clientes`), você deve criar uma verificação para detectar se o tempo do cliente expirou (não precisa ser um longo tempo, 30 segundos está *mais do que bom*).

Primeiro criamos um `HashMap` para relistar:

```java
Map<String, Date> relista;
```

Depois criamos um loop para verificar o que ainda está dentro do tempo limite:

```java
relista = new HashMap<String, Date>(); // Limpa relista para aproveitá-la novamente.

Date agora = new Date();
agora.add(Calendar.SECOND, -30); // 30 segundos mencionado anteriormente, edite conforme necessidade.

for (String key : clientes.keySet()) {
    Date timer = clientes.get(key);
    if (!agora.after(timer)) {
       // Se o item ainda está dentro dos 30 segundos então "mantém na lista".
       relista.put(key, timer);
    }
}

clientes = relista; // Atualiza a lista de clientes conectados.
```

### Sessões

O último exemplo que citei é apenas uma forma simples de entender como listar, porém o uso de `getRemoteSocketAddress` não é exato pois o IP pode mudar (tanto em uma rede privada quanto na internet). A maneira mais garantida seria usando sessão, porém será necessário bibliotecas externas para facilitar o trabalho (é possível fazer sem, mas exige bastante tempo para desenvolver algo). Existem bibliotecas que podem ajudá-lo, como por exemplo o [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) (claro que se for usado para HTTP).

Comment: `List<String> clientes = new ArrayList<String>();`...`clientes = addr;`... Não tem algo errado aqui não?

Comment: @GustavoCinque Obrigado é na hora da correria, já foi corrigido.