# Como saber se um cliente socket desconectou?

Tags: java, socket

Eu tenho um servidor que possui um `List` com todos os clientes conectados.

O cliente conecta e a conexão é gerenciada em uma thread exclusiva com loop infinito de comunicação.

O problema quando derrubo o cliente ou fecho a conexão, não sei como implementar no servidor que o cliente encerrou a conexão. Sei que se fecha sozinho a conexão, mas o objeto socket do cliente ainda fica salvo no `List`.

Resumindo não sei o momento em que devo chamar o método `remove` do `List`.

Já tentei usar o método `isConnected` ou `isClosed` do socket. Não funcionou.

**UPDATE**

Estou fazendo dessa forma e está dando certo.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    //loop espera mensagem do client
    while(true){
        //aguarda receber uma mensagem
        String response = receive();
        //condição para encerrar comunicação
        if(response==null)
            break;
        //valida mensagem
        Message msg;
        try{
             msg = new Gson().fromJson(response, Message.class);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //mensagem invalida, volta ao inicio do laço e espera nova mensagem.
            continue;
        }            
        //cria thread para tratar mensagem
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                managerMessage(msg);
            }
        }).start();
    }
    System.out.println("Cliente desconectou");
    //remove socket da lista de conexões abertas
    server.removeConnection(this);

}
```

O método receive() que criei ele fica esperando uma mensagem do cliente,
enquanto não receber uma mensagem  o método não conclui. Notei que quando derrubo o cliente, o receive() começa a retornar `null`, por enquanto está dando certo, não sei se é a melhor forma.

```
public String receive(){
    //espera receber mensagem
    while(receiver.hasNextLine())
        return receiver.nextLine();//quando um mensagem chega retona
    return null;
}
```

obs.: `receiver` é um `Scanner` foi criado da seguinte forma 
`new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());`

Comment: **Relacionado:** [É possível saber quantos clientes estão conectados ao ServerSocket?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45321/3635)

Answer (score 1):

O momento certo de considerar a conexão fechada é quando o InputStream retorna nada ao ser lido. Enquanto a conexão ficar aberta, o read() bloqueia até que pelo menos um byte possa ser retornado, e readLine() bloqueia até receber uma linha inteira.

No seu caso, este comportamento está acontecendo dentro da chamada a hasNextLine(), que provavelmente chama o readLine() do InputStream e está bloqueando corretamente enquanto a conexão está aberta, ou retorna imediatamente com vazio quando a conexão fecha.

Answer (score 1):

Uma [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) é lançada se o cliente desconectar inesperadamente, pois uma vez que o socket não consegue mais ler dados significa um *fim inesperado*.

Você pode ver um exemplo de um servidor de chat que fiz para responder à outra pergunta aqui no SO usando a referida exceção no seguinte link:

> https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/blob/master/random-code/src/main/java/chat/Server.java