# Como posso saber se um socket está "à escuta" do lado do servidor?

Tags: java, android, socket, conexão

Quando eu uso a função [`isConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()) do [`java.net.Socket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html), no lado do cliente, e ela me retorna `true` eu posso ter a certeza que o servidor está "à escuta"? Senão como eu posso saber? Só com um tempo de espera entre estabelecer conexão e começar "a escrever"?

PS: Coloquei a tag Android porque não sei se tem influência.

Comment: Não posso afirmar, mas talvez isto esteja relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45393/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu só quero saber se o servidor está a ler o que eu escrevo no socket antes de começar a escrever.

Comment: Então, só usando a API do Socket simplesmente não tem como. O cliente pode ter desconectado e não notificado o Socket, e o servidor não fica sabendo. Uma técnica que eu costumo usar é Heart Beat, que é mandar pacotes específicos opacos, só pra verificar se chega. Caso não chegue a resposta, podemos assumir que o outro lado Socket morreu*.

Comment: Sim, por isso citei a resposta, talvez não tenha como ter certeza e por isto a resposta sugere coisas como um "timer", mas se tratando de 
"comunicação persistente", talvez tenha sim como saber, claro que eu diria que o cliente precisaria ficar enviando um sinal "constante".

Comment: @Wakim é ao contrário. Eu quero saber se o servidor está "a ler" o que eu mando.

Comment: Mas nesse caso se você enviar e falhar você sabe que o servidor não está acessível. Mas você quer checar isso antes? Ai tem de fazer um "ping" nele para verificar a disponibilidade.

Comment: @Wakim o mal é que não tenho essa funcionalidade. Mas obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Então Jorge, uma possibilidade é usar o protocolo ICMP pra executar um ping no servidor, seria algo semelhante a um ping do terminal, pode ser a forma mais simples, a não ser que o servidor esteja bloqueando a porta :( Olhando com mais calma, parece que a classe `InetAddress` provê essa funcionalidade através do método [`isReachable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)), ele executa um ping no servidor (lembrando que pode ser bloqueado ainda).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível saber quantos clientes estão conectados ao ServerSocket?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45321/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-saber-quantos-clientes-est%c3%a3o-conectados-ao-serversocket)

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite Jorge,

Como a documentação diz:
Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.

Quando uma conexão socket fecha ela não muda o estado do objeto, logo continua true.

A melhor abordagem é você implementar no seu client/server um ACK. Seu cliente faz um ACK para seu servidor e o mesmo responde. Caso ocorra um erro na escrita no socket vc sabe que a conexão foi perdida e se conecta novamente.

Abs